# "getting requirement to build wheel error " when trying to install pillow , seaborn

Tags: python, scipy, python-imaging-library, metadata

The output shows

Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [61 lines of output]
The Meson build system
Version: 0.62.2
Source dir: /private/var/folders/7j/kvhbym5j0q9499lwlx3p8hh80000gn/T/pip-install-jv74wxwd/scipy_4adc41f671b54d0b9da66215aabea411
Build dir: /private/var/folders/7j/kvhbym5j0q9499lwlx3p8hh80000gn/T/pip-install-jv74wxwd/scipy_4adc41f671b54d0b9da66215aabea411/.mesonpy-0ypirwuf/build
Build type: native build
Project name: SciPy
Project version: 1.9.0
C compiler for the host machine: cc (clang 12.0.5 "Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)")
C linker for the host machine: cc ld64 650.9
C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (clang 12.0.5 "Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)")
C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld64 650.9
Host machine cpu family: aarch64
Host machine cpu: arm64
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: NO
Library m found: YES

```
  ../../meson.build:41:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['gfortran'], ['flang'], ['nvfortran'], ['pgfortran'], ['ifort'], ['g95']]
  The following exception(s) were encountered:
  Running "gfortran --version" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gfortran'"
  Running "gfortran -V" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gfortran'"
  Running "flang --version" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flang'"
  Running "flang -V" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flang'"
  Running "nvfortran --version" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvfortran'"
  Running "nvfortran -V" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvfortran'"
  Running "pgfortran --version" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pgfortran'"
  Running "pgfortran -V" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pgfortran'"
  Running "ifort --version" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifort'"
  Running "ifort -V" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifort'"
  Running "g95 --version" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'g95'"
  Running "g95 -V" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'g95'"
  
  A full log can be found at /private/var/folders/7j/kvhbym5j0q9499lwlx3p8hh80000gn/T/pip-install-jv74wxwd/scipy_4adc41f671b54d0b9da66215aabea411/.mesonpy-0ypirwuf/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
  + meson setup --native-file=/private/var/folders/7j/kvhbym5j0q9499lwlx3p8hh80000gn/T/pip-install-jv74wxwd/scipy_4adc41f671b54d0b9da66215aabea411/.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2 --prefix=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10 /private/var/folders/7j/kvhbym5j0q9499lwlx3p8hh80000gn/T/pip-install-jv74wxwd/scipy_4adc41f671b54d0b9da66215aabea411 /private/var/folders/7j/kvhbym5j0q9499lwlx3p8hh80000gn/T/pip-install-jv74wxwd/scipy_4adc41f671b54d0b9da66215aabea411/.mesonpy-0ypirwuf/build
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "/private/var/folders/7j/kvhbym5j0q9499lwlx3p8hh80000gn/T/pip-build-env-k7yc84gu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 909, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      with _project(config_settings) as project:
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
      return next(self.gen)
    File "/private/var/folders/7j/kvhbym5j0q9499lwlx3p8hh80000gn/T/pip-build-env-k7yc84gu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 888, in _project
      with Project.with_temp_working_dir(
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
      return next(self.gen)
    File "/private/var/folders/7j/kvhbym5j0q9499lwlx3p8hh80000gn/T/pip-build-env-k7yc84gu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 547, in with_temp_working_dir
      yield cls(source_dir, tmpdir, build_dir)
    File "/private/var/folders/7j/kvhbym5j0q9499lwlx3p8hh80000gn/T/pip-build-env-k7yc84gu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 463, in __init__
      self._configure(reconfigure=bool(build_dir) and not native_file_mismatch)
    File "/private/var/folders/7j/kvhbym5j0q9499lwlx3p8hh80000gn/T/pip-build-env-k7yc84gu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 494, in _configure
      self._meson(
    File "/private/var/folders/7j/kvhbym5j0q9499lwlx3p8hh80000gn/T/pip-build-env-k7yc84gu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 477, in _meson
      return self._proc('meson', *args)
    File "/private/var/folders/7j/kvhbym5j0q9499lwlx3p8hh80000gn/T/pip-build-env-k7yc84gu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 472, in _proc
      subprocess.check_call(list(args))
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['meson', 'setup', '--native-file=/private/var/folders/7j/kvhbym5j0q9499lwlx3p8hh80000gn/T/pip-install-jv74wxwd/scipy_4adc41f671b54d0b9da66215aabea411/.mesonpy-native-file.ini', '-Ddebug=false', '-Doptimization=2', '--prefix=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10', '/private/var/folders/7j/kvhbym5j0q9499lwlx3p8hh80000gn/T/pip-install-jv74wxwd/scipy_4adc41f671b54d0b9da66215aabea411', '/private/var/folders/7j/kvhbym5j0q9499lwlx3p8hh80000gn/T/pip-install-jv74wxwd/scipy_4adc41f671b54d0b9da66215aabea411/.mesonpy-0ypirwuf/build']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  [end of output]
```

How should i fix it ?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you are missing `gfortran` a fortran compiler nesscary for installing scipy. Try installing gfortran from [here](https://fortran-lang.org/learn/os_setup/install_gfortran).

If that doesn't help, you can install scipy from wheel [here](https://pypi.org/project/scipy/#files). Then run `pip install filename.whl` to install the package.

Or try a different installation method listed on [scipy's website](https://scipy.org/install/).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are on a Mac. Installing gcc with homebrew: `brew install gcc` did the trick for me.